# SQLITE3 Integrity Error: Why am I getting this?

Tags: sql, flask, sqlite

I hate how it doesn't tell exactly what the error is but I've explored whether it was the data type that caused this error.

This is my function that is erroring:

```
def insert_recipe(recipe_id, recipe_name, img_link, recipe_link):
    with sql.connect('app.db') as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO recipes (recipe_id, recipe_name, img_link, recipe_link) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (recipe_id, recipe_name, img_link, recipe_link))
        connection.commit()
```

This is the error page:
[image]

This is my function that cause on it to display it in my profile:

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def display_profile():
    id = request.values.get('id')
    title = request.values.get('title')
    img_link = request.values.get('img_link')
    link = request.values.get('link')
    print(type(id), type(title), type(img_link), type(link))
    insert_recipe(id, title, img_link, link)
    insert_savedRecipes(current_user.id, id)
    recipes = loadSavedRecipes()
    return render_template('profile.html', name=current_user.username, recipes=recipes)
```

My SQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE recipes (
  r_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  recipe_id text NOT NULL,
  recipe_name text NOT NULL,
  img_link text NOT NULL,
  recipe_link text NOT NULL
);
```

I have checked the data types for all the columns, and according to the terminal, they are all strings. In addition, the function does seem to work because it inserts the recipe into the database table recipes. However, when I click on the profile tab in the navigation bar, that's when this all errors.

So I'm not sure why I am getting this error when my table seems to be inserting correctly as pictured below:

[image: table]

Answer (score 1):

All columns in the table are set to be `NOT NULL`, while the first one (R_ID) is set to be the `PRIMARY KEY`, which can't be NULL anyway. So - `INSERT` has to insert all 5 columns in order for it to work.

You are, on the other hand, inserting 4 columns.

Note the last line of the screenshot you attached:

> sqllite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: recipes.recipe_id

So, make sure that you really pass RECIPE_ID to the function.

Comment: Yes, it's really passing in the recipe_id. So when you insert into the SQL database table, I thought that r_id would naturally be added to increment? Does this not how it actually works?

Comment: Naturally? Not, as far as I can tell, unless you create a table that uses the "identity" or "auto-increment" or whatever it might be called in a database system you use. Declaring the column `integer primary key` does it automatically in SQLite, so - yes, the **R_ID** will be auto-incremented. However, error explicitly mentions **RECIPE_ID**, so - either the engine is lying, or you actually don't pass its value (although you claim you do).

Comment: Yes, it seems that it is actually passing in the value through my print statements and the r_id auto increments so still not sure why not null constraint is failing

Comment: Just for testing purposes - if you can afford it - drop the table, and recreate it without specifying NOT NULL for all columns. Run your code again, and you'll see what gets inserted, and what does not. I presume that RECIPE_ID will really remain empty (i.e. NULL).